# How do I pass multiple parameters to a subroutine?

Tags: abap, subroutine

I am trying to pass multiple `parameters` to a subroutine, but I get the following error:

> Incorrect nesting: before the statement "FORM", the structure introduced by "FORM" must be concluded with "ENDFORM"

Here is my code:

```
CASE p_choose.
  WHEN 'UMK'.
    PERFORM umk USING: p_modul,
                       p_e_pal,
                       p_vbeln,
                       p_e_umk.
"some other cases
ENDCASE.

FORM umk USING: p_modul,
                p_e_pal,
                p_vbeln,
                p_e_umk.
ENDFORM.
```

Where is my mistake? How can I pass multiple parameters? Or isn't it possible at all? Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but when writing new code I'd recommend to use (static) methods or at least function modules. FORMs are a pain to debug.

Comment: I'll keep that in my mind, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complete your own answer which is the correct solution, let me explain the reason of the error which is due to a misunderstanding of how the [chained statements](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenchained_statements.htm) work, by showing the equivalent code without the chained statements.

Your old code with chained statements (symbols `:` and `,`):

```
FORM umk USING: p_modul,
                p_e_pal,
                p_vbeln,
                p_e_umk.
ENDFORM.
```

is exactly equivalent to this code without chained statements:

```
FORM umk USING p_modul.
FORM umk USING p_e_pal.
FORM umk USING p_vbeln.
FORM umk USING p_e_umk.
ENDFORM.
```

Hence the obvious syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

I already found the solution by myself.
The mistakes are the "," after every parameter.

The correct code would be:

```
CASE p_choose.
  WHEN 'UMK'.
    PERFORM umk USING p_modul
                      p_e_pal
                      p_vbeln
                      p_e_umk.
"some other cases
ENDCASE.

FORM umk USING p_modul
               p_e_pal
               p_vbeln
               p_e_umk.
ENDFORM.
```

Comment: For more information, refer to [ABAP documentation - Chained statements](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenchained_statements.htm).